# Improve code to make div to fill the browser width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I managed to create this code to make the `div.full_width_no_padding` to fully fill the width of the browser. It works fine in desktop browsers but it doesn't work in mobile devices like iphone, nexus, etc.

Is there any other way to do this?

js

```
(function ($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".full_width_no_padding").width($(window).width());
    var marginLeft = ($(window).width() - $('#region-content').width()) / 2;
    $(".full_width_no_padding").css( "margin-left", -marginLeft );

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $(".full_width_no_padding").width($(window).width());
        var marginLeft = ($(window).width() - $('#region-content').width()) / 2;
        $(".full_width_no_padding").css( "margin-left", -marginLeft );
    });

   });   
}(jQuery));
```

html

```
<div id="region-content" style="width:960px">
    <div class="full_width_no_padding" >content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have a missing double quote for the style attribute of `#region-content`

Comment: @Brewal thanks, was a typo.

Comment: Have you tried to connect your phone to your computer and debug this ? I really like to do this with my nexus 5 and google chrome. It is just like debugging a tab in a browser, and you see changes in live on your phone.

Comment: Can you use plain old CSS for this instead of JavaScript? I'm probably missing something, because this looks like reinventing the wheel

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro If your container is centered with a specific width and you don't have the hand on the html, I think it can only be done with js

Comment: @Brewal you are right, there is no way to do this just using css, afaik.

Comment: how about `transform:translate(-50%, 0%)`? Independently of the width, it will translate the div 50% of its width to the left

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Yes, but how do you make it 100% of the screen then ?

Comment: Can you specify how it renders under mobile devices ?

Comment: @Brewal I will try to update a capture or something.

Comment: Again, and my apologies in advance because I must still be missing something: you want an element to occupy 100% of the screen but to be contained within another element that occupies 960px? Why not put it outside of that restraining element directly?

Comment: what are the styles for `#region-content` and `.full_width_no_padding`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro let's say you use a CMS and have a content centered in a page. On a specific page, you want to load a slider module in the middle of your content... You cannot change the html.

Comment: This is what I meant by using only CSS and not JS: http://jsfiddle.net/ef4qpyu5/ (`.full_width_no_padding` grows independently of the size of the parent to occupy 100% of the screen)

Comment: @Brewal You are changing the JS, why not the HTML? Even if you  could not change it directly on the HTML source, you could change it with JS: `$("#region-content .full_width_no_padding").appendTo("body");`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Not the html because of what I said. But yes, changing the HTML with js seems to be a lot better than trying to position the inner div. I would simply split the parent to cover every cases

Answer (score 0):

You should let this code execute after the DOM is ready, if you don't do this the code might be executed before the DOM is ready and then the changes won't be applied because your code can't find the elements in the DOM.

In jQuery it's easy, you just wrap your code in a `$(function() { <code here> });` block, so you'll get:

```
$(function() {

    $(".full_width_no_padding").width($(window).width());
    var marginLeft = ($(window).width() - $('#region-content').width()) / 2;
    $(".full_width_no_padding").css( "margin-left", -marginLeft );
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $(".full_width_no_padding").width($(window).width());
        var marginLeft = ($(window).width() - $('#region-content').width()) / 2;
        $(".full_width_no_padding").css( "margin-left", -marginLeft);
    });

});
```

For more information, see: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: How could it worked under desktop browsers without it ?

Comment: It's not specific to a browser, it's a race condition, sometimes the DOM is ready before the Javascript executes, sometimes it isn't. Maybe the browser of his desktop computer can load the DOM fast enough.

Comment: The code is executed after the DOM is ready, I just forgot to include it in my question. I updated it.

Comment: @JPashs the code in your question is different from the one in my answer. Your code will not wait until the DOM is ready, it will execute this function as soon as it has the chance, with as the first argument the `jQuery` variable, and it will assign it to the `$` character inside the function body. That's different than the approach that I use, which is specially for waiting for the DOM. For more information, see: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @rednaw I see, sorry. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @rednaw the code is not fired at all. I guess the element is not there the code runs. Imho the function '$(document).ready(function() {...
'  has to be in the code.

Comment: @rednaw keep in mind that my code works in desktop browsers. I think the problem is related to get the size of the window in mobile devices.

Comment: I doubt that, jQuery is a well tested library. Did you try my solution?

Answer (score -3):

I will explain this in very easy steps:

1- Delete that Javascript.

2- Add this to your css:

```
body,html{padding:0;margin:0;}
```

3- Make sure all it's parents have `width:100%`.
   Generally, you can assume that *all* block-level elements have (by default) `width:100%`.

4- Profit!

Comment: In this question, the width of the parent seems to be a constraint

Comment: Parent has to 960px, I can't not change this, if it were 100% then what is the point of using js for this?

Comment: @JPashs You said "I managed to create this code to make the div.full_width_no_padding to fully fill the width of the browser.", and you asked for improvements. There it is. Improved and fills the browser window.